# Android GoogleApiClient

Tags: android

Preciso usar a classe GoogleApiClient mas não estou conseguindo importa-la. Já importei as lib do [google-api-java-client](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/Setup), mas pelo que vi não existe o pacote `com.google.android.gms.common.api.*`.

Esta classe está dentro do `GooglePlayServices`? Como faço para atualizar o meu `GooglePlayServicesLib`?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Está usando Eclipse ou o Android Studio? A princípio ela vem dentro do jar do `GooglePlayServices` sim. Chegou a seguir esse tutorial http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html?

Comment: Estou usando Eclipse, já segui aquelas instruções. Eu percebi que meu GooglePlayServices mostra Android 2.2 . Sabe como eu posso atualizar isso?

Comment: Que eu saiba, posso estar enganado, mas o GooglePlayServices não define seu compile level. Você deve ir no SDK Manager r baixar as versões relativas ao seu minSDK e targetSDK. Além disso dê uma olhada se não tem nenhuma atualização para o Google Support Repositories e nem do Google Play Services na area Extra. Se puder inclua uma imagem dessa indicação da versão 2.2.

Comment: Wakim, eu tive que atualizar tudo no SDK Manager para mostrar a opção de atualizar o Google Play Services. Antes não mostrava opção para atualizar, estava na versão 13. Depois que atualizei tudo, até o ADT, ai sim mostrou a opção para atualizar o GooglePlayServices. Atualizou para a versão 21, eu importei novamente para o meu projeto e agora  esta importando o pacote que eu precisava. Muito Obrigado.